# How do I know if an external DLL enters a function?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have a Win32 application (console application) which uses an external DLL. The DLL exports two functions (Run and SecretFunction) and I need to know when the DLL enters the SecretFunction. I load the DLL on run-time (I get the path via command line arguments).

I can't use shared events.

The two hints I got is to use some similar logic to the exceptions methods and to maybe use VirtualQuery/VirtualProtect.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Clarification:

My program will call the Run function. The Run function may or may not call the SecretFunction. I want to know from within my program if the SecretFunction was called or not.

I have the following code, so I have the address of the function:

```
pfn_SecretFunction pfnSecretFunction = (pfn_SecretFunction)GetProcAddress(pluginDLLModule, "SecretFunction");
```

Comment: create a sandwich dll that just pipes the calls and tells you when it is accessed.

Comment: I can't. I can't control the external DLL. It will be given to me.

Comment: Are you trying to detect when the `SecretFunction` is called from within your process (your program). Or are you trying to detect it for every instance of the DLL by any process running on the host machine?

Comment: I added some clarification to the question - sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: I don't have access to the code of the secret function.

Comment: @godmoney: if you have a pointer to the function, you have access to its code, although in a fairly hard-to-read format (machine code). You can use detours, like mox suggested, or you can manually rewrite that machine code, if you have experience with assembly coding (easier than it sounds!).

Answer (score 1):

Inject the DLL and add code in the function you want to trace (monitor).

Comment: you can use Detours (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) for this.

Comment: When using injection (based on the mechanism of your choice), you don't need the code of the target you inject! (otherwise you would not need injection).

Comment: take a look at this (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5178/DLL-Injection-and-function-interception-tutorial) kind of sample.

Answer (score 0):

Throw an Exception in the DLL when reaching the (SecretFunction) function and catch (and swallow) the exception in the exe (console).

Comment: I could do that if I had access to the DLL - but I don't :/